# Why does \begin{center} sometimes fail to center a tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[UTF8,fontset=none,scheme=chinese,twoside,a5paper]{ctexbook}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK TC}
\setCJKsansfont{Noto Sans CJK TC}
\ctexset{chapter/format=\LARGE\bfseries\centering\sffamily,chapter/number=\arabic{chapter}}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[cam,a4,center,noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc,intersections,quotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=圖}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}

\chapter[]{} 

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\draw [gray] (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
\fill (0,0) circle [radius=1pt]; 
\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (195:2cm);
\coordinate [label=left:$B$] (B) at (125:2cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C) at (55:2cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$D$] (D) at (-15:2cm);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\pic [draw,angle radius=3mm] {angle = A--B--C};
\pic [draw,angle radius=3mm] {angle = B--C--D}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\draw (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0) coordinate (x axis);
\draw (0,-3.5) -- (0,3.5) coordinate (y axis);
\draw [gray] (0,0) coordinate (O) circle [radius=3cm];
\path [name path=upward line] (3,0) coordinate (B) -- (3,3);
\path [name path=sloped line] (O) -- (30:6cm);
\path [name intersections={of=upward line and sloped line, by=C}];
\draw (C) node [above right,inner sep=1pt] {$C$} -- (O) node [below left,inner sep=1pt] {$O$}; %CO
\draw (C) -- node [right,inner sep=1pt] {$\tan x$} (B) node [below right,inner sep=1pt] {$B$}; %CB, tanx
\pic [draw,angle radius=1.5mm] {right angle = x axis--B--C}; %CB垂直x axis
\coordinate (A) at (30:3cm);
\coordinate (D) at (A|-x axis);
\draw (A) node [above,xshift=2pt,yshift=1pt] {$A$} -- node [left,inner sep=1pt] {$\sin x$} (D) node [below,inner sep=1pt] {$D$}; %AD, sinx
\pic [draw,angle radius=1.5mm] {right angle = x axis--D--A}; %AD垂直x axis
\draw (A) -- (B); %AB
\path (O) -- node [above] {$1$} (A); %半徑1
\pic [draw,angle radius=5mm,angle eccentricity=1.5,"$x$"] {angle = B--O--A};
\node [right,inner sep=1pt] at (25:3cm) {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Below is the output. 圖 1-2 is not centered. How can I solve this problem? I would appreciate your help with this situation.

[image]

Comment: Looks centered to me.  Keep in mind that `\tan x` also contributes to the bounding box.  Try `node [right,inner sep=1pt,overlay] {$\tan x$}`.

Comment: Please state your alignment objective more succinctly. E.g., are you aiming to have the circle's centers be aligned?

Comment: Put a layer of `\fbox` on top of the second `tikzpicture` so you can see if it's aligned

Comment: @Mico Yes, I,m aiming to have the circle's centers be aligned. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there something that prevents you from using `\begin{figure} \centering` instead of `\begin{center}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tikzpicture`s *are* centered. In the second one the bounding box is not symmetric around the origin. One can extend the bounding box to be symmetric. (I apologize for removing the Chinese characters, my editor cannot handle them.)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[cam,a4,center,noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc,intersections,quotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=fig}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test} 

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\draw [gray] (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
\fill (0,0) circle [radius=1pt]; 
\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (195:2cm);
\coordinate [label=left:$B$] (B) at (125:2cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C) at (55:2cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$D$] (D) at (-15:2cm);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\pic [draw,angle radius=3mm] {angle = A--B--C};
\pic [draw,angle radius=3mm] {angle = B--C--D}; 
\draw (current bounding box.south west) 
-- node[midway]{$\times$} (current bounding box.south east) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\draw (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0) coordinate (x axis);
\draw (0,-3.5) -- (0,3.5) coordinate (y axis);
\draw [gray] (0,0) coordinate (O) circle [radius=3cm];
\path [name path=upward line] (3,0) coordinate (B) -- (3,3);
\path [name path=sloped line] (O) -- (30:6cm);
\path [name intersections={of=upward line and sloped line, by=C}];
\draw (C) node [above right,inner sep=1pt] {$C$} -- (O) node [below left,inner sep=1pt] {$O$}; %CO
\draw (C) -- node [right,inner sep=1pt] {$\tan x$} (B) node [below right,inner sep=1pt] {$B$}; %CB, tanx
\pic [draw,angle radius=1.5mm] {right angle = x axis--B--C}; %CB__x axis
\coordinate (A) at (30:3cm);
\coordinate (D) at (A|-x axis);
\draw (A) node [above,xshift=2pt,yshift=1pt] {$A$} -- node [left,inner sep=1pt] {$\sin x$} (D) node [below,inner sep=1pt] {$D$}; %AD, sinx
\pic [draw,angle radius=1.5mm] {right angle = x axis--D--A}; %AD__x axis
\draw (A) -- (B); %AB
\path (O) -- node [above] {$1$} (A);
\pic [draw,angle radius=5mm,angle eccentricity=1.5,"$x$"] {angle = B--O--A};
\node [right,inner sep=1pt] at (25:3cm) {$x$};
\draw (current bounding box.south west) 
-- node[midway]{$\times$} (current bounding box.south east) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\draw (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0) coordinate (x axis);
\draw (0,-3.5) -- (0,3.5) coordinate (y axis);
\draw [gray] (0,0) coordinate (O) circle [radius=3cm];
\path [name path=upward line] (3,0) coordinate (B) -- (3,3);
\path [name path=sloped line] (O) -- (30:6cm);
\path [name intersections={of=upward line and sloped line, by=C}];
\draw (C) node [above right,inner sep=1pt] {$C$} -- (O) node [below left,inner sep=1pt] {$O$}; %CO
\draw (C) -- node [right,inner sep=1pt] {$\tan x$} (B) node [below right,inner sep=1pt] {$B$}; %CB, tanx
\pic [draw,angle radius=1.5mm] {right angle = x axis--B--C}; %CB__x axis
\coordinate (A) at (30:3cm);
\coordinate (D) at (A|-x axis);
\draw (A) node [above,xshift=2pt,yshift=1pt] {$A$} -- node [left,inner sep=1pt] {$\sin x$} (D) node [below,inner sep=1pt] {$D$}; %AD, sinx
\pic [draw,angle radius=1.5mm] {right angle = x axis--D--A}; %AD__x axis
\draw (A) -- (B); %AB
\path (O) -- node [above] {$1$} (A);
\pic [draw,angle radius=5mm,angle eccentricity=1.5,"$x$"] {angle = B--O--A};
\node [right,inner sep=1pt] at (25:3cm) {$x$};
\path let \p1=($(O)-(current bounding box.south
west)$),\p2=($(current bounding box.south east)-(O)$)
 in ([xshift=-\x2]O) ([xshift=\x1]O);
\draw (current bounding box.south west) 
-- node[midway]{$\times$} (current bounding box.south east) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here you see that in the second picture the horizontal center of the bounding box is not under the origin.

[image]

Here we extended the bounding box to become symmetric.

Of course,

```
\draw (current bounding box.south west) 
-- node[midway]{$\times$} (current bounding box.south east) ;
```

is only used for illustration purposes and needs to be removed in your real document in the end.

**ADDENDUM*: As [Henri Menke pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548181/why-does-begincenter-sometimes-fail-to-center-a-tikzpicture/548183#comment1384648_548181), one reason for the asymmetric bounding box is the node containing `$\tan x$`. However, the "main culprit" is the auxiliary line you use for intersections,

```
\path [name path=sloped line] (O) -- (30:6cm);
```

If you replace it by

```
\path [name path=sloped line,overlay] (O) -- (30:6cm);
```

and follow Henri's advice, you get

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc,intersections,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\draw (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0) coordinate (x axis);
\draw (0,-3.5) -- (0,3.5) coordinate (y axis);
\draw [gray] (0,0) coordinate (O) circle [radius=3cm];
\path [name path=upward line] (3,0) coordinate (B) -- (3,3);
\path [name path=sloped line,overlay] (O) -- (30:6cm);
\path [name intersections={of=upward line and sloped line, by=C}];
\draw (C) node [above right,inner sep=1pt] {$C$} -- (O) node [below left,inner sep=1pt] {$O$}; %CO
\draw (C) -- node [right,inner sep=1pt,overlay] {$\tan x$} (B) node [below right,inner sep=1pt] {$B$}; %CB, tanx
\pic [draw,angle radius=1.5mm] {right angle = x axis--B--C}; %CB__x axis
\coordinate (A) at (30:3cm);
\coordinate (D) at (A|-x axis);
\draw (A) node [above,xshift=2pt,yshift=1pt] {$A$} -- node [left,inner sep=1pt] {$\sin x$} (D) node [below,inner sep=1pt] {$D$}; %AD, sinx
\pic [draw,angle radius=1.5mm] {right angle = x axis--D--A}; %AD__x axis
\draw (A) -- (B); %AB
\path (O) -- node [above] {$1$} (A);
\pic [draw,angle radius=5mm,angle eccentricity=1.5,"$x$"] {angle = B--O--A};
\node [right,inner sep=1pt] at (25:3cm) {$x$};
\draw (current bounding box.south west) 
-- node[midway]{$\times$} (current bounding box.south east) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The bounding box is also symmetric, yet if you put the picture next to some other object, it may overlap with its neighbor.